# Get memory usage information of nanoFramework-project/device

Tags: nanoframework

I am a classical embedded C/C++ programmer and want to give the nanoFramework a go. Have some stuff running but wondering how much heap I am using and how much space is still free. And also if it is possible to generate a map file, where I can see how much space my program uses in flash and how much space I still have left.... I am certainly no C# expert, but guess that there is no section in Ram with statically allocated memory. Further also wondering what the stack size is and whether I have control over the stack size.

I have checked the Project settings, but gives me an error message:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmRgI.png)

Did some googling but so far could not find any information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that by calling the [GC](https://docs.nanoframework.net/api/nanoFramework.Runtime.Native.GC.html#nanoFramework_Runtime_Native_GC_Run_System_Boolean_) with the option to either force the GC to run, or not.

BTW, excellent choice with nanoFramework. ;) Have fun!